# Google Cloud Datastore query by all kinds in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

In Google Cloud Console using GQL I can do this.

[image]

```
SELECT __key__
```

And this will return all keys from all kinds of the current namespace. One of the use case, is to delete tenant. Tenant will not exist as soon as no records existing inside.
I can't do this from the node.js via google cloud client library, because, it seems like function doesn't support that.

```
db.createQuery("5630110493310976", undefined).select("__key__");
```

One interesting thing. This will work and will return all entities from all tenants.

```
db.createQuery().select("__key__");
```

What am I missing?

I know, that I can bypass it by using __kind__ query, grab all kinds and go through them, but, I'm looking to more elegant way first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I launched this query under another project in which such namespace is not exist. Therefore I though that the result is wrong and datastore or client library not support it. 
So, the correct way to fetch all entities of all kinds from single namespace would be.

```
db.createQuery("5630110493310976", undefined).select("__key__");
```

And to fetch all entities from all namespaces

```
db.createQuery().select("__key__");
```